# Installing Epson Stylus NX125 drivers?

Tags: software-installation

Does anyone know how to install drivers for my Epson Stylus NX125 all in one printer/scanner on Ubuntu? My windows xp hard drive was attacked by a virus and it locked up my applications so my cousin installed Ubuntu on my second 20 gig drive to access e-mail/Internet

Answer (score 1):

Natty should have direct support for installing printer drivers from the [Epson site](http://avasys.jp/eng/linux_driver/download/lsb/epson-inkjet/escp/).

Your NX125 printer is a supported printer.

If either you are not using Natty, or Natty doesn't for whatever reason automatically recognise your printer when you plug-it in, then go to the above website and search for your model number "NX125"

You'll see various download options - download either the i386.deb file or the amd64,deb file together with the manual.  The choice of the deb depends on whether you are using 32bit desktop or 64bit desktop respectively.

The instructions for installing the deb files are in the manual.

In summary

```
cd Downloads
sudo dpkg -i <debfilename>
```

The SimpleScan utiility should again see your scanner part of the printer without any issues - if it doesnt though, it might need some extra drivers - the drivers are in the similar area of the website [here](http://www.avasys.jp/lx-bin2/linux_e/spc/DL1.do#productinfo)